# nginx location url not find file

Tags: nginx

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /yyy {
        root /;
        index xxx.html;
    }
```

in root folder, I am sure there are xxx.html in yyy folder

```
/yyy/xxx.html
```

I go http://localhost/yyy

But I get this response

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.6</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I expecting nginx will go `/yyy` this folder and use
configuration `index xxx.html` as response, but it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you just need to update the `root` directive to the right directory, if the `yyy` folder is in the root directory, you can simply modify your server configuration like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /yyy {
        root /;  #update this line to the correct directory path!!!
        index xxx.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you give my some hint. I try something and know how it work. Thank your response.